# passing value to handler

Tags: c#, winforms, fileopendialog

I have code like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{ 
    string ext = Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
    if(string.Compare(ext, ".FDB") == 0)
    {
        string fileName = openFileDialog1.SafeFileName;
        string fileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName);
        string databaseTxt = @"C:\Users\arist\AppData\Roaming\TDWork\";
        string[] database = { fileDirectory + fileName };
        if (Directory.Exists(databaseTxt))
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(databaseTxt + "databases.txt", database);
        }
        else
        {
            DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(databaseTxt);
            System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(databaseTxt + "databases.txt", database);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Fajl koji ste izabrali nije Firebird baza (.FDB)");
        e.Cancel = true;
    }                        
}
```

Now, i want to create more buttons that open same file dialog. Problem is that i want to pass openFileDialog directory to different textboxes. So logic is this:

If i open with button1, pass value to textbox1,
If i open with button2, pass value to textbox2,
if i open with button3, pass value to textbox3.

So i wanted to create int check (1, 2, 3) so when i press button1, it pass check = 1 to OpenDialog1_FileOk, so i just do switch there and do actions.

Problem is i do not know how to pass it to handler, and if that is possible. Also if there is any other solution, please write it.

Comment: where do you want to use your text from the textbox?

Comment: @MongZhu nowhere, just to display

Comment: ok, so where do you want to display it? in the same `Form` ? or in the `OpenfileDialog` ?

Comment: @sowjanyaattaluri I know that, read my question again. I know how to use same handler, but i need handler's action to depend on button that invoked it

Comment: @MongZhu in the same form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you could use your openfiledialog just like this, without handling a whole new function for it:

```
if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK){
    //...code
}
```

Second, for your goal you'll have to be sure that the names of your controls are exactly ending on the digit you want (e.g. "button1" and "textbox1"). Then you can do it like this:

```
void Button1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        //MessageBox.Show(bt.Name[bt.Name.Length - 1].ToString());
        if(openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            if(!Path.GetExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName).EndsWith(".FDB"))  //checking if the extension is .FDB (as you've shown in your example)
            {   
                MessageBox.Show("Fajl koji ste izabrali nije Firebird baza (.FDB)");
                return; //return if it's not and no further code gets executed
            }

            string fileDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(openFileDialog1.FileName); //getting the directory
            string nameOfMyButton = (sender as Button).Name;    //you get the name of your button
            int lastDigitOfMyName = Convert.ToInt16(Name[Name.Length - 1]); //returns the number of your button
            TextBox neededTextboxToShowDirectory = this.Controls.Find("textbox" + lastDigitOfMyName, true).FirstOrDefault() as TextBox; //this will search for a control with the name "textbox1"
            neededTextboxToShowDirectory.Text = fileDirectory; //you display the text
            //... doing the rest of your stuff here
        }
    }
```

Comment: But if i do it like this, i can not cancel event if extension is not .fdb

Comment: You can always put your check above the code, man. It's simple like that, just with a simple `return` you can tell your code to not execute further if your first check is not fullfilled.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a private field where you save temporarily the text of your `TextBox` and deploy it in the click event like this:

```
private int whichButton = 0;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    whichButton = 1;
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}


private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    whichButton = 2;
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}


private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    whichButton = 3;
    openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
}
```

use then the `whichButton` to choose

```
private void openFileDialog1_FileOk(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
{ 
    switch (whichButton)
    {
         ....
    }


}
```

Comment: Yea, that is one of solutions i got on mind but i thought there is more efficiency way of doing it instead of declaring global variable. Thanks anyway.

Comment: @Pacijent I'm quite sure there is. Was just a second late. You may still take a look.

Comment: I just read again your question, my solution doesn't seem quite right. Dont't you want to pass the resulting value from the `OpenFileDialog` to the respective `TextBoxes` ?

Comment: @Pacijent I edited my answer. Is it now closer to what you had in mind? Personally, I like the answer D. Petrov suggests.

Comment: Yea i have done it like this from beginning. Changed your code a little and it is working normal. D. Petrov is also good solution. Currently i am doing one more solution because i know logic of doing it now, so i will post it after i finish.